# TCP Connection Keep-Alive direction

Tags: tcp

When a connection have not received packets for a certain period of time (default 2 hours), it should send KEEP-ALIVE packets.

My question is, who will start sending KEEP-Alive packets, the client, server or both?

Comment: What kind of server/client are you using?

Comment: I would think it would be the side that initiated the connection.

Comment: windows 7 and linux 2.6.x

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either side will, assuming:

1. the OS is configured to do so ([linux](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/TCP-Keepalive-HOWTO/usingkeepalive.html), [windows](https://serverfault.com/questions/40250/enabling-system-wide-tcp-keepalives-on-a-windows-system))
2. the application configured the socket with SO_KEEPALIVE via setsockopt() ([linux](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/TCP-Keepalive-HOWTO/), [windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee470551(v=vs.85).aspx)).

If both sides have identical keepalive settings, then you'll see them both kick off a keepalive at nearly the same time.